# .NET Core Azure servicebusqueue number of messages

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am currently working on a .NET Core project where I use the Microsoft.Azure.Servicebus version 1.0 NuGet package found here:  https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus

The problem I have is that I haven't found any method to get a queue's number of active messages. This used to be pretty easy with .NET framework using the ServicebusNamespace.NamespaceManager, referring to a queue and use the *.ActiveMessageCount*.

Is this possible in some other way in this library with .NET Core 1.1?

Comment: I think you mean this repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET Standard client (`Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`) is deliberately not providing management operations. It states that management operations should not be performed at run time. Management operations are extremely slow.

> Is this possible in some other way in this library with .NET Core 1.1?

Yes, it is possible.

Instead of the `NamespaceManager` that was available with the old client (`WindowsAzure.ServiceBus`), there's a ServiceBus management library ([`Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/Fluent))

You will need to do the following:

- Authenticate using `ServiceBusManager`
- Access the namespace you're interested in via `ServiceBusManager.Namespaces`
- Filter out the entity you're interested in by locating it under `ServiceBusManager.Namespaces.Queues`/`ServiceBusManager.Namespaces.Topics`. For subscription you'll need to locate one via `ITopic` object.
- Once you've got your entity (`IQueue`, `ITopic`, or `ISubscription`), you'll be able to access the message counts.

I'm not a big fan of this approach. Rather than each developer reinventing this wheel, Azure Service Bus team should have provided a helper library to replace `NamespaceManger`. You can always [raise an issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/new?title=Provide%20a%20substitute%20for%20NamespaceManager&body=If%20not%20in%20this%20package,%20in%20a%20separate%20one.%20Developers%20should%20not%20reinvent%20this%20concept.) or vote for an issue that [was closed](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65).

Management operations were introduced back in version 3.1.1 with [pull request #481](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/pull/481).

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you for an excellent answer. I really miss the precious approach but also hope that this might be changed and simpler in the future.

Comment: Your are welcome Nicklas. If enough people chime in to let know there should be an abstraction, perhaps ASB team will add another package to address it. Alternative would be a community driven one. GitHub issue tracker is the best way too let know something should be done about it.

Comment: During the waiting time, you can use the Mossharbor code, this code provide a way simple to management features that you need in SB

https://github.com/Mossharbor/AzureWorkArounds.ServiceBus

Comment: Waiting time should be short - there's already a [PR](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/pull/481) in place :)

Answer (score 8):

It is now possible using the latest version of the [Service Bus library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/) (3.1.1):

```
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management;

var client = new ManagementClient(connectionString);
var queue = await client.GetQueueRuntimeInfoAsync(queuePath);
var counts = queue.MessageCountDetails;

var subs = await client.GetSubscriptionRuntimeInfoAsync(topic, subscription);
var countForThisSubscription = subs.MessageCount;  //// (Comes back as a Long.)
```